# Generate alt texts for upload images with AI in TYPO3?

Tags: image, text, typo3, artificial-intelligence, alt-attribute

I am searching for a way to automatically generate alt texts for images when uploading them in the TYPO3 backend? Is there any extension that can do this, or similar extensions for generating alt texts (probably based on AI)?
I am glad about every tip or recommendation. :)

I searched for some ai alt text extension, but found nothing suitable. Something like alttext.ai, but as TYPO3 Extension, not WordPress...
https://wordpress.org/plugins/alttext-ai/
https://alttext.ai/

Answer (score 0):

We had done some work with AWS Rekognition at that time. Now this is not the simple extension insllation for alt texts, but maybe you can use it as inspiration for your service?

https://github.com/ayacoo/aws-meta